# What is the life span of Lord Brahma according to Vedas?

Tags: gods, life-span

In my childhood, I had read about the life span of Brahma. can someone please enlight this topic?

Comment: yes as per Bhagwat Gita , above calculations are right, but it also stated that after 100 years life of lord Brahma he died.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hinduism had their own scale of measuring mass, length and time, and they have done this to both extremes. Time can be measured to very small units as well as to humongous scales.

Quoting [Hindu Units of Time|Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Reckoning_of_time_for_Brahma) and [BG 8.17](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-08-17.html),

> - 1 human fortnight (15 days) = 1 day (light) or night of the Pitṛs
> - 1 human month (30 days) = 1 day (light) and night of the Pitṛs
> - 30 days of the Pitṛs = 1 month of the Pitṛs = (30 × 30 = 900 human days)
> - 12 months of the Pitṛs = 1 year of the Pitṛs = (12 months of Pitṛs × 900 human days = 10800 human days)
>
>   The lifespan of the Pitṛs is 100
>     years of the Pitṛs (= 36,000 Pitṛ days = 1,080,000 human days = 3000
>     human years)
> - 12000 Deva Years = Life Span of Devas = 1 Mahā-Yuga.
> - 1000 Mahā-Yugas = 1 Kalpa = 1 day (day only) of Brahma
>
>   (2 Kalpas constitute a day and night of Brahma, 8.64 billion human years)
> - 30 days of Brahma = 1 month of Brahma (259.2 billion human years)
> - 12 months of Brahma = 1 year of Brahma (3.1104 trillion human years)
> - 50 years of Brahma = 1 Parārdha
> - 2 parardhas = 100 years of Brahma = 1 Para = 1 Mahā-Kalpa (the lifespan of Brahma)(311.04 trillion human years)

In short as per Hindu traditions,

The life span of any Hindu deva spans nearly (or more than) 4.5 million years and the lifespan of Brahma is 311.04 trillion human years.

SideNote: Age of Universe is estimated to be 13.8 billion years, nowhere close to the lifetime of Brahma. It's probably a few days old.

Comment: "The Brahma mentioned here is not the Brahma from Trimurty, this is the Brahman."  Where did you get this from?  Day of Brahma does refer to Brahma from the Trimurthy.  He creates the world during the day, and then it's destroyed while he's sleeping.

Comment: yes, that was a misunderstanding.