# What do Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva do after 1 Kalpa when Brahmadev goes to sleep?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahma

What do Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva do after 1 Kalpa when Brahmadev goes to sleep ?

As per [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/265/10089) answer a day of Lord Brahma is

> 4(yuga)*1000.
>     4,320,000 years * 1000 = 4,32,00,00,000 years is 1 day of Brahma (1 Kalpa).

After which Lord Brahma goes to sleep. When Lord Brahma goes to sleep then every thing turns into dark. Which will exist for same period i.e for 1 kalpa ?

When everything goes in dark then what exactly Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva do? Do they go to sleep or something else?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan does it mean Lord Vishnu is in sleeping position and Lord Shiva is doing Tandava dance.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad Yeah, it does.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan if Lord Vishnu goes to sleep then who is going to preserve janaloka and above loka. coz if Vishnu goes to sleep then it is going to be a big problem for soul residing in jana loka and above loka.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't think Lord Vishnu is sleeping and Shiva is doing tandav. There might be something else

Comment: What do you think Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva are doing now? Whatever they are doing now, they will do after the day of Brahma provided that some other lokas are still there.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria But there has to be some details as of we have information about Lord Brahmdev.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62957/discussion-on-question-by-praveen-gaikwad-what-do-lord-vishnu-and-lord-shiva-do).

Comment: 3 lower worlds get destroyed (bhu, bhuva, suvah) - higher 4 worlds still exist, and jivas inhabit those.

Answer (score 1):

```
4,320,000 years * 1000 = 4,32,00,00,000 years is 1 day of Brahma ...
```

First of all, as per the original verse found in [Moksha Dharma Parva](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/mahabharat/text-with-translation/vol-viii/chapter-231/topic-1) -- page 177 -- verse 20, there is **no mention of "celestial years"**. Hence 1 cycle of 4 Yuga-s is 4800 + 3600 + 2400 + 1200 = 12000 years.

> चत्वार्याहुः सहस्राणि वर्षाणां तत्कृतं युगम्।
> तस्य तावच्छती संध्या संध्यांशश्च तथाविधः ।।२०।।
> Four thousand <strike>celestial</strike> years is the duration of the first or Krita age. The morning of that cycle consists of four hundred years and its evening is of four hundred years.

The Brahma's day is said to be ***sahastra*** such yuga cycles. Now Sanskrit word ***sahastra* may mean "thousand" or "so many"**. But "so many" is subjective, it can mean anything less than or more than 1000. If we choose 1000, then the total duration of day/night will be 12000000 = 12 million years.  So Brahma's full cycle will be 24 million years.

> The learned say that these twelve thousand years constitute what is called a yuga. A thousand such yugas compose a single day of Brahman. The same is the duration of Brahman's night.

---

```
What do Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva do after 1 Kalpa when Brahmadev goes to sleep ?
```

Since you haven't tagged your Qn as "mythology", I am answering this from regular perspective. Trinity of lords -- Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva (not Shankara), should be interpreted as supreme reality -- what is known as *Brahman* in Gita. This *Brahman* is said to be neither existent nor non-existent, yet immutable.

The relative "creation" & "destruction" happens during *Brahman*'s day. However, during its night nothing remains. Gita doesn't use word "destroy" for this. It just uses *"Avyakta"* .. i.e. "unmanifest" or "inexpressible".

To answer your Qn: Absolutely nothing remains, this includes *Brahman* (trinity) itself. However to express this, the word *Nirguna Brahman* is used, which means "inexpressible". Everything merges back to the truest nature of *Brahman*, which is also called liberation (see the combined meaning of BG 9.7 & BG 14.2).

> BG 8.17, 8.18, 8.19 - Knowing that thousand eras constitute a day of Brahman, [and] thousand eras complete a night, are the people who know day, [and] night. On arrival of day, all manifestations originate from "Unmanifest"; On arrival of night they annihilate into [what is] known as "Unmanifest" only. This [same] elementary world only happens again & again; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.

You may refer [this anwser](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16085/10490) for further clarifications.

Comment: unmanifest is the state of deep sleep.

Comment: @Fire. there are differences of interpretations. For this answer, I am following Gita's translation. For example, *"BG 9.4 - This whole world is pervaded by Me in My unmanifest form. All beings exist in Me, but I am not contained in them!"* -- means the world exists (i.e. day) during "unmanifest" form. Now this cannot be "deep sleep", because world exists during the day. Another meaning of "unmanifest" is also beyond "unmanifest" -- *"BG 8.20 - But different from that "unmanifested", is the another eternal "unmanifest" reality, which is not destroyed when all beings are destroyed."*

Comment: "Everything merges back to the truest nature of Brahman, which is liberation." I think the  liberation is totally different thing. Dissolution should not be interpreted as liberation. Liberation or Moksha is the [permanent](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2457/277) or ultimate liberation from Samsara (and not limited to Kalpa).

Comment: @Pandya, According to *"BG 9.7 - at the end of Brahman's day, everything assumes 'My' nature"*. From verse *"BG 14.2 - assuming 'My' nature (saa-dharma) is the supreme state"*. So at least in that context, "liberation" seems guaranteed for everyone. probably what you mean is "self realisation". That's a subset of "liberation". Not everyone may attain "self realisation" followed by "liberation". But everything attains "liberation" for sure. Else the Brahma's day would not finish.

Comment: So you believe Kali Yuga is already over ? The various scholars who say we are in year 5000+ of kali are wrong ?

Comment: @ram, According to Yukteshwar Giri (a Kriya yogi & Jyotisha), Kaliyuga is already over and we are much beyond that. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9965/1049), which is not mine. However, there are multiple theories around "yuga"-s. I don't have any strong belief towards anyone. My leaning is more towards what is mentioned in MahAbhArata's Moksha Dharma Parva as stated in above answer(s). So far this is the only authentic scripture found around Yuga theory IMO.

Comment: when did this Yukteswar theory gain popularity ? All vedic scholars (just go to any proper temple in India) say Kali is 4,32,000 years old. All symptoms of Kali mentioned in Puranas are flourishing well now. Mahabharata war occurred ~3000 B.C. There is no record that Kalki avatara happened yet. Yet this new-found theory has followers.. strange are the ways of the world. Now let's look at the 2 shlokas prior to that one

Comment: It gradually goes from small time units to bigger ones of humans, pitrus, devas. shloka 18's translation says 'calculating by days and nights of human beings i shall tell you about years of Brahman (this should be Brahma not Brahman)', where does 'human beings' word come from.. jeevaloukike ? rather it would make sense shloka is using previous unit of year (which is deva's year)..

Comment: now look at shloka 31 - 'sahasra-yuga-paryantam' - literal translation according to you would be 'thousand yugas' make up 1 day, when we all know it refers to chaturyuga or mahayuga, not single 'yuga'.. because we have to take into context previous shloka 29, which defines yuga as 12000 of these years. similarly, we have to take in previous context before deciphering a meaning.